# Get value from a td <p> class with tr id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi it sounds complicated but here is my table:

```
<tr id="product709663341" class=" inBasket">
    <td>
        <span class="valueToSort">709663341</span>
        <p class="ref">709663341</p>
    </td>
    <td class="desc">
        <p class="productTitle">i am the text</p>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

How can i get the value of the p (i am the text) with the id of the tr? ( because there is multiple tr)

Well it has to be code javascript because it is injecting the code.

It possible with the code jQuery also.

Comment: Did you try something? You can do this by traversing the DOM. The jQuery documentation tells you about lots of neat functions to do this. It'll be more fun and exciting if you read the documentation then work on it yourself.

Comment: Well i tried $('.productTitle').attr('product709663341'); but it is undefined.

Comment: Well, that's just guessing! `attr` has nothing to do with this. You should spend more time reading the documentation and figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value like so (with jQuery):

```
$('#product709663341').find('.productTitle').text();
```

`text()` get the inner text of element you select.
I use `find()` because is more efficient.

You can use:

```
`$('#product709663341 .productTitle')`
```

or

```
`$('#product709663341').find('.productTitle')`
```

In the first case, jQuery search all `.productTitle` and after, get only one (with the parent equal to `#product709663341`).

In the second case, jQuery search `#product709663341` and after, inner this element search `.productTitle`.

Source: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: It works! Thank you! i can't vote up i don't enough repulation...

Comment: one question, what is the different between find() and not find()?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#product709663341").find(".productTitle").text();
```

Or:

```
$("#product709663341 .productTitle").text();
```

These will return "i am the text".

Answer (score 0):

If using JQuery
$("#product709663341 .productTitle").text()
Using document queryselector would be very similar.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest seems to be

```
$('tr p.productTitle')
```

Comment: He wants a specific one. With a specific ID.